# Colormap for errorbars in x-y scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, errorbar, color-mapping

I have a time series of data for which I have the quantity, y, and its error, yerr. I would now like to create a plot that shows y against phase (i.e. time / period % 1) with vertical errorbars (yerr). For this, I typically use pyplot.errorbar(time, y, yerr=yerr, ...)

However, I would like to use a colorbar/map to indicate the value of time in this same plot.

What I thus do is the following:

```
pylab.errorbar( phase, y, yerr=err, fmt=None, marker=None, mew=0 )
pylab.scatter( phase, y, c=time, cmap=cm )
```

Unfortunately, this will plot unicolored errorbars (default is blue). Since I have ~1600 points per plot, this makes the colormap of the scatter plot disappear behind the error bars. Here's a picture shows what I mean:

[image]

Is there a way that I can get the error bars to be plotted using the same colormap as the one used in the scatter plot? I don't want to call errorbar 1600 times...

Answer (score 17):

In addition to changing the color, another suggestion is to change the `zorder` of the error bars versus the scatter plot. This focuses the user on the data and draws out the general shape of the errors (which I think is your intention).

```
from pylab import *

# Generate some random data that looks like yours
N = 1000
X = random(N)
Y = sin(X*5) + X*random(N)*.8
Z = random(N)
ERR = X*random(N)

# These are the new arguments that I used
scatter_kwargs = {"zorder":100}
error_kwargs = {"lw":.5, "zorder":0}

scatter(X,Y,c=Z,**scatter_kwargs)
errorbar(X,Y,yerr=ERR,fmt=None, marker=None, mew=0,**error_kwargs )
xlim(0,1)
show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Hooked! I didn't know about the zorder kwarg. Although this is not exactly the answer I was hoping for, it'll do for the moment.
MoiJaiunvelo was right, ideally I would like to have the errorbars plotted in the same color as the datapoints.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for the solution for a while and I finally found a way through:

```
from pylab import *

#data
time = arange(100.)
signal = time**2
error = ones(len(time))*1000

figure(1)
#create a scatter plot
sc = scatter(time,signal,s=20,c=time)

#create colorbar according to the scatter plot
clb = colorbar(sc)

#create errorbar plot and return the outputs to a,b,c
a,b,c = errorbar(time,signal,yerr=error,marker='',ls='',zorder=0)

#convert time to a color tuple using the colormap used for scatter
time_color = clb.to_rgba(time)

#adjust the color of c[0], which is a LineCollection, to the colormap
c[0].set_color(time_color)

fig = gcf()
fig.show()
xlabel('time')
ylabel('signal')
```

Comment: Great solution, but how about the color of the caps? Is there a way to update the color of the caps using the colormap?

Answer (score 7):

Sorry to dig this back up, but just run into something similar myself and this was my solution based on previous responses.

This sets the marker, errorbars, and caps as the same colour in the colormap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#data
time = np.arange(100.)
signal = time**2
error = np.ones(len(time))*1000

#create a scatter plot
sc = plt.scatter(time,signal,s=20,c=time)

#create colorbar according to the scatter plot
clb = plt.colorbar(sc)

#convert time to a color tuple using the colormap used for scatter
time_color = clb.to_rgba(time)

#loop over each data point to plot
for x, y, e, color in zip(time, signal, error, time_color):
    plt.errorbar(x, y, e, lw=1, capsize=3, color=color)
```

**EDIT:**
After changing to matplotlib v3.1.1 the above stopped working, but here's a workaround:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#data
time = np.arange(100.)
signal = time**2
error = np.ones(len(time))*1000

#create a scatter plot
sc = plt.scatter(time,signal,s=0,c=time)

#create colorbar according to the scatter plot
clb = plt.colorbar(sc)

#convert time to a color tuple using the colormap used for scatter
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cm as cm
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(signal), vmax=max(signal), clip=True)
mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='viridis')
time_color = np.array([(mapper.to_rgba(v)) for v in signal])

#loop over each data point to plot
for x, y, e, color in zip(time, signal, error, time_color):
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color=color)
    plt.errorbar(x, y, e, lw=1, capsize=3, color=color)
```

Finally for completeness, here's a plot of what it should produce:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `ecolor` optional argument in `pylab.errorbar` as you use the `color` argument in `pylab.scatter`:

```
pylab.errorbar( phase, y, yerr=err, fmt=None, marker=None, mew=0, ecolor=time )
```

Comment: @ Hooked, I think Random wants his/her errorbars to have the same colour as his/her datapoints. Your solution is good since it puts errorbars below datapoints and improve the clarity of the graph, but it does not fix the error bar colour issue.

Comment: @ Moi Jaiunvelo: I've tried this and it's not working for me, unfortunately. Could you please explain how to get the time array (type float and runs typically from [0, 2000.]) to a valid ecolor array?