# matplotlib one legend entry too much

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, errorbar

I am trying to do an errorplot with different marker-colors in python 2.7. Additionally I am including to line plots.
I found a way here: [matplotlib errorbar plot - using a custom colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290493/matplotlib-errorbar-plot-using-a-custom-colormap) using a scatter plot for the colors and errorbar() for the bars.

As you can see in my example code, in the legend I always get one entry too much (just at the top). I cannot figure out, why. Tried to exclude it, which did not work. Did not find something helpful either, as I cannot really call the first legend entry.

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline


data = pd.DataFrame()
data['x'] = range(10)
data['y'] = data.x
data['err'] = .5
data['col'] = np.where(data.y<5,'r','b')

### setup 1-1 line
lin = pd.DataFrame()                            # setting 1-1 line
lin['x'] = range(10)
lin['y'] = range(10)

### setup 1-2 line
lin['x2'] = lin.x
lin['y2'] = lin.y

plt.errorbar(data.x, data.y, yerr = data.err, \
                   xerr = .3, fmt=' ', markersize=4, zorder = 1)
plt.scatter(data.x,data.y, marker='o', color = data.col, zorder = 2)
plt.plot(lin.x,lin.y,'g-')
plt.plot(lin.x2,1.8*lin.y2,'r-')
plt.legend(['','1-1 line', '1-1.8 line','holla','molla'], loc=4)
```

What I get is:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with your code.

Comment: runs just fine for me both with spyder and jupyter.
numpy: 1.11.0, pandas: 0.18.0, mpl: 1.3.1, maybe version difference?

Comment: Yes, it runs, but I don't get the extra legend entry

Comment: sure? try to insert some text in the first legend entry. A friend of mine just gets the same

Comment: I have mpl 1.5.1. Putting text in the first entry assigns it to the green line

Comment: For me, removing the empty label helps: `plt.legend(['1-1 line', '1-1.8 line','holla','molla'], loc=4)`.

Comment: maybe try updating to mpl 1.5? 1.3.1 is two and a half years old now...

Comment: after some troubles upgrading mpl I finally made it and... it works!! seems it was really a version issue. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

To clean this whole thing up, I post a proper answer instead of comments.
The problem could be solved by upgrading matplotlib from 1.3.1 to 1.5.1. Easy as that.