# Color errorbars in 2D according to colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

This is a rather simple issue at first glance, but I haven't been able to find a solution. There's a similar (old) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208814/colormap-for-errorbars-in-x-y-scatter-plot-using-matplotlib) but the [closest answer given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18409403/1391441) does not seem to apply to error bars in both dimensions.

I need to generate an "errorbar" plot where both error bars (in the x and y dimensions) are colored according to the values in the `cc` array.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some random data
aa = np.array([3.581, -0.721, 0.137, 0.645, 0.12, 0., -3.236, 0.248, -5.687, 0.816])
e_aa = np.array([0.111, 0.991, 0.446, 0.07, 0.814, 0., 0.088, 0.805, 0.178, 0.552])
bb = np.array([6.671, 1.219, 0.119, -1.972, 1.834, 0., 4.93, 1.833, -11.542, -0.439])
e_bb = np.array([0.143, 1.316, 0.609, 0.094, 1.127, 0., 0.116, 1.227, 0.216, 0.726])

# The color array
cc = np.array([0.50344083, 0.49961867, 0.5055576, 0.48970365, 0.5078516, 0.49643923, 0.50089907, 0.50129157, 0.49627974, 0.5052376])

plt.errorbar(aa, bb, yerr=e_bb, xerr=e_aa, fmt='none', ecolor=cc)
plt.show()
```

fails with a:

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 0.50344083
```

whether I use the `ecolor` or `color` argument.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution. The trick is to map the floats to a valid colormap using `matplotlib.cm`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

# Some random data
aa = np.array([3.581, -0.721, 0.137, 0.645, 0.12, 0., -3.236, 0.248, -5.687, 0.816])
e_aa = np.array([0.111, 0.991, 0.446, 0.07, 0.814, 0., 0.088, 0.805, 0.178, 0.552])
bb = np.array([6.671, 1.219, 0.119, -1.972, 1.834, 0., 4.93, 1.833, -11.542, -0.439])
e_bb = np.array([0.143, 1.316, 0.609, 0.094, 1.127, 0., 0.116, 1.227, 0.216, 0.726])

# The color array
cc = np.array([0.50344083, 0.49961867, 0.5055576, 0.48970365, 0.5078516, 0.49643923, 0.50089907, 0.50129157, 0.49627974, 0.5052376])

# Define function to map (normalized) values in `cc` to a colormap
cmap = cm.viridis
norm = Normalize(vmin=cc.min(), vmax=cc.max())

plt.errorbar(aa, bb, yerr=e_bb, xerr=e_aa, fmt='none', ecolor=cmap(norm(cc)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`plt.errorbar()` generates a three separate objects: the line between points, the lines for each errorbar cap (if any), and a `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection` containing the errorbar lines themselves. The `ecolor` argument is ultimately passed to `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection.set_color()`, which accepts a:

> Matplotlib color argument (all patches have the same color) or a sequence of rgba tuples; if it is a sequence the patches will cycle through the sequence.

Your array `cc` is neither of these. The method receives a sequence, so it tries to set the color of each line in the collection to each element of the sequence. But those elements are just single floats, which are not valid matplotlib colors.

To fix this, generate a list of tuples, with each tuple specifying the RGB[A] color of the line segments for each errrorbar. For example, using the other data you specified in your question, the colors can be set as:

```
cc = np.random.rand(aa.size, 3) # Random colors, RGB tuples uniform on (0, 1)
collections = plt.errorbar(aa, bb, yerr=e_bb, xerr=e_aa, fmt='none', ecolor=cc)
```

This generates a plot like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but, although your explanation is clear, it doesn't really solve the issue.

Comment: @Gabriel How does this not solve the issue? You want to specify colors for the errorbar lines as floats, which is exactly what this does.

Comment: This assigns random colors, that's not what I needed.

Comment: Of course it assigns random colors, because I have no idea what colors you actually want. Just put in the RGB values you *do* want, instead of calling `np.random.rand`. The point was to show you how to use the `ecolor` argument, the actual colors are irrelevant. But seems like you've got your own solution, so all is good.

Comment: The colors I want are those encoded by the floats in the `cc` array. Your solution re-writes this array.